# Группировка элементов в NSMutableArray() swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

Добрый день. Имеется `JSON` массив,полученный из сети.Пример одного элемента:

```
{
  id: 5
  title: "example"
  house: {
         houseID:"100"
         address:"example street" 
         }
}
```

Не получается правильно сгруппировать элементы по `houseID`.Многие элементы могут иметь одинаковый `houseID`

```
var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]()
var sections = NSMutableArray()

  if let resData = swiftyJsonVar.arrayObject {
                self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]

            }


            for json in self.arrRes {
                //нужно сгруппировать все элементы по house.addr

                if let data = json["house"] {
                    let address = data["address"] as? String
                    let houseID = data["houseID"] as? String

                    print(address)
                }

                self.sections.addObject(json)

            }
```

В конечном итоге хочется видеть массив с одним houseID и т.д и т.д,чтобы всё это потом передать в `uiCollectionView` для секций

Comment: Так сгруппировать или отсортировать? И почему по `houseID`, а не `id`?

Comment: точнее сгруппировать. почему `houseID` ? такова цель моя )

Comment: Т.е. по `"houseID"` складывать `json` хотите?

Comment: Да.Причём,нужно уже в NSMutableArray() поместить.
чтобы получилось
first element :{массив всех элементов с одним houseID}
second element:{массив с другим houseID} и т.д

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разбирайте сразу в `Dictionary`:

```
var dict = [String: [AnyObject]]() //ну либо NSMutableArray если так хотите вместо [AnyObject], но тогда не .append, a .addObject()
for json in self.arrRes {
    if let data = json["house"] {
        let houseID = data["houseID"] as? String
        if let _ = dict[address] {
            dict[address]?.append(json) //.addObject(json)
        } else {
            dict[address] = [json]
        }
    }
}
```

---

UPD. Сразу в `NSMuatableArray` все разбирать думаю будет проблематично, больше проверок. Просто после формирования `Dictionary` перекиньте массивы в `NSMuatableArray`:

```
var arr = NSMutableArray()
for elements in dict {
    arr.addObject(elements.1)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,но на выходе не совсем то выходит,что ожидалось

Comment: @Konstantin по комментарию "first element :{массив всех элементов с одним houseID} second element:{массив с другим houseID}" понял, что необходимо так. Или же Вы хотите в `NSMutableArray` добавлять сгруппированные по `houseID`  `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: `Или же Вы хотите в NSMutableArray добавлять сгруппированные по houseID NSMutableArray?`
Всё верно.Попробую ещё раз описать по-народному: т.е пробежаться по всему основному массиву и разложить по полкам все элементы. каждая полка - книги с одинаковым `houseID` :)

Comment: @Konstantin, обновил ответ, может подойдет.

Comment: @Konstantin, снова не понял что Вы хотите. Массивы собираются в один массив. Получается на выходе `((элементы с одним houseID),(элементы с другим houseID),(элементы с третьим houseID))`. Что должно быть на выходе?